# How do I find out what the SHA should be for a release tarball on github?

Tags: github

See for example https://github.com/grpc/grpc/releases. I see the commit SHAs but not the tarball SHAs.

Comment: Release sha is not shown here. Why do you need it? You can download the file and calculate the hash on your machine. I dont think you need extra integrity check as the files are downloaded over ssl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub doesn't provide hashes for release tarballs and zip files.  For the autogenerated source code archives (as opposed to additional release archives uploaded by the maintainer), you can use `git archive` to produce an equivalent archive from the repository if you're concerned about integrity.

This probably would be a nice feature request for GitHub.